# What is the general way to rewrite an ODE with respect to a change in coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE : $y' = f(x, y)$

I change for coordinates $(r, s) = (g(x, y), h(x, y))$. What is the equation like in terms of r and s ?

If it can help, in my case, $(r, s) = (y.x^{-k}, ln(x))$. I can express x(r, s) and y(r, s) but I don't know what $y'$ becomes and how to get $^{ds}_{dr}$ in. Thanks

Comment: Try doing $dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} dr +\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} ds$ and $dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} dr +\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} ds$?

Comment: great technique ! it works well. you should write it as an answer

Comment: Too short as an answer :)